# jquery, textarea in an html function, the cursor goes away

Tags: jquery, cursor, textarea

I have this simple Jquery code:

```
$('.answerComment').click(function() {
    $(this).children('.answerForm').html('<textarea></textarea>');  
});
```

but as soon as I'm clicking on the textarea the cursor goes away, and if i want to write something i need to keep the left button of the mouse clicked

any idea why?

Comment: I assume it's because the new textarea is a child of `.answerComment` and clicking it will trigger this same function (which replaces the textarea with a new one).

Comment: @Juhana thanks for your answer, but there is no old textarea, I just want a texteare to appear in .answerForm when i click on .answComment

Comment: You didn't understand the comment. When you click on `.answerComment`, it creates the textarea; when you click on the textarea to start typing on it, the same event is triggered and the textarea is replaced with another one.

Comment: @Juhana oh ok,sorry I didnt understand first place. I will show the texteare outside .answerComment thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.answerComment').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName == 'TEXTAREA') return;
    $(this).children('.answerForm').html('<textarea></textarea>');  
});
```

But you have selected not the best way to show your textarea.

Comment: You are welcome. However I would recommend you to show your `textarea` outside of the  `.answerComment` container.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the click() is also called when clicking on a child-element

you can avoid this by checking which element is actually clicked

```
$('.answerComment').click(function(e) {

    if ($(e.target).hasClass("answerComment")){
        $(this).children('.answerForm').html('<textarea></textarea>');    
    }


});
```